# What is the use of {} block in Java

Tags: java

Hello Friends what is the use of having just a block in Java class

```
public class StaticExample {
  {
    System.out.println("I m here...");
  }
}
```

Comment: don't know why is called `StaticExample`

Comment: Other than *instance initialiser*, the magic phrase you may be looking for is *double-brace initialisation idiom*. Yeah, `{` or `{{` is difficult to google.

Comment: @texasbruce: but this is not an example of a static initializer.  This is clearly a non-static initializer.

Answer (score 7):

That's an initialization block. It gets executed when a new instance is created. If you think that that's a job for the constructor, it is a place where you can put code that is executed no matter which constructor is used. They are executed in the order they appear, before the constructor. If you put `static` in front of an initialization block, it becomes a static initialization block, which is executed as soon as the class is loaded.

Comment: Technically they're executed after the super constructor call and before the rest of the body. This is actually important if the superclass ctor calls a virtual method.

Answer (score 6):

It's called an initializer block and is invoked every time an instance of the class is created.

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

The code is invoked before the code in the constructor and doesnt depend on the latter.

```
public class InitializerExample {

    public InitializerExample() {
        System.out.println("InitializerExample");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("I'm here...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InitializerExample();
    }
}
```

will produce

```
I'm here...
InitializerExample
```

It is documented in the official tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: Are these copied into the constructor at the beginning? The end? Undefined behavior?

Comment: The code is inserted before the constructor

Comment: The initialization block is executed before the constructor body. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689224/inline-initialization-blocks-in-java

Comment: `super()` first then `{}` then your constructor block code